# How does assembly in ARM use the compare mnemonic?

Tags: assembly, arm

In the code below, when I compile and execute it using `./filename ; echo $?` I get `4`. Why?

```
.global _start

_start:

    mov R1,#1
    mov R2,#2
    cmp R1,R2
    BGT bigger

bigger:

    mov R0,#4
    B end

_default:

    mov R0,#3

end:

    mov R7,#1
    swi 0
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: @RaymondChen I don't know how to use gdb,if you can guide me through it ,it would be wonderful.

Comment: you can't format is as well. My advice: do not touch assembler before you learn how to use basic tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are programming assembly language you already have an instruction set reference right like the ARM Architectural Reference Manual (ARM ARM), correct?  And when you were reading that manual under operation for the CMP instruction you found:

```
if ConditionPassed(cond) then
alu_out = Rn - shifter_operand
N Flag = alu_out[31]
Z Flag = if alu_out == 0 then 1 else 0
C Flag = NOT BorrowFrom(Rn - shifter_operand)
V Flag = OverflowFrom(Rn - shifter_operand)
```

Then under the branch instruction

```
if ConditionPassed(cond) then
if L == 1 then
LR = address of the instruction after the branch instruction
PC = PC + (SignExtend(signed_immed_24) << 2)
```

and for both the cond field describes the conditions required to execute or not execute an instruction

```
1100 GT Signed greater than Z clear, and either N set and V set, or
N clear and V clear (Z == 0,N == V)

1110 AL Always (unconditional)
```

The AL is implied if no other condition is specified.

When you were reading this manual what part of this did you not understand?